# Show logon process on windows 8

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, windows-8.1, logon-scripts

I'm experimenting with server admin on windows 2008 since I started a new tech job and want to learn things. I'm using a windows 8.1 pro client computer.

The question is, is there any way to show the logon messages like "please wait for the user profile service" and "running logon scripts" etc.

I've searched group policy (including local GP on the client) and drawn a blank. 
Any help will be met with appreciation and virtual hugs.

Comment: May I ask why you want to do that? That message has virtually no usable information for the user.

Answer (score 1):

The setting you want is located in `Computer Configuration - Policies - Administrative Templates - System`.  In local policy, remove the Policies entry.

Depending on the version of the ADM/ADMX templates you're using the name of the setting is called either `Display highly detailed status messages` or `Verbose vs normal status messages`.  If I recall correctly, they both set the same registry value and have the same effect.